# Why phpmyadmin.conf file doesn't exist after installing?

Tags: server, apache2, phpmyadmin

I've followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install *phpMyAdmin* on the server which uses *ubuntu 14.04*. I've entered all commands and restarted apache, but when I open this path through the browser:

```
http://domain_name_or_IP/phpmyadmin
// I replace my real IP with domain_name_or_IP
```

It throws:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server
```

---

Also here is the result of this command:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/conf-available# ls
```

[image]

See? there is not any file related to phpMyAdmin. Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Please copy and paste the `ls` command output

Comment: @pa4080 Is there any hope?

Comment: @pa4080 Wow great .. I will check your email out. thank you so much

Comment: Are you run this comand `sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` manually?

Comment: @pa4080 Yes, I read somewhere I have to do that. *(but seems it been wrong)*

Comment: I think you was forgot to `sudo service apache2 restart`. You can accept the the duplicate suggestion and up-vote the answer if you want :)

Comment: @pa4080 I did it :). Also isn't is consulting to you if I change the password of my server?

Comment: I'm already logged out.

Comment: I know you logged out, I want to change the password because I pasted in here for 1 min

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64222/discussion-between-pa4080-and-stack).